# How do I bind an ObservableCollection to an AvalonDock DocumentPaneGroup?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, avalondock

I need to load a collection of items as documents in AvalonDock 2.0. These objects inherit from an abstract class, for which I want to render a frame inside the document depending on which subclass are.

This is my XAML:

```
<ad:DockingManager Background="Gray" DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=OpenProjects}" 
        ActiveContent="{Binding Path=CurrentProject, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OpenProjects/Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
    <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassAViewModel}">
                        <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassAProject.xaml" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassBViewModel}">
                        <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassBProject.xaml" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassCViewModel}">
                        <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassCProject.xaml" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Grid.Resources>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
    <ad:LayoutRoot>
        <ad:LayoutPanel>
            <ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <ad:LayoutDocumentPane>

                </ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
            </ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </ad:LayoutPanel>
    </ad:LayoutRoot>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

So far I've achieved to show as many documents as items are in the `OpenProjects` collection, but I can't seem to show anything inside each document.

Plus, I don't know if I'm using `ActiveContent` properly: I want to assign to `CurrentProject` the ViewModel assigned on the current active document.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are not able to see any content is of the way you defined your `LayoutItem` templates. This can't work.
Also consider to use a custom control instead of the `Frame`. The `Frame` is very heavy. Unless you don't need to display HTML, avoid this control. Content navigation is very easy to implement, in case you want to show navigable content. Just wrap your document content into a `UserControl`.

You are using the `ActiveContent` property properly.

To fix your problem you have three recommended solutions, where the first doesn't exactly meet your requirements. Since you defined the `DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate` wrong, I will show it anyway.

### Solution 1: Local `LayoutItemTemplate`

In case you only need a single template for all `LayoutDocument` and `LayoutAnchorable` containers, you can use the `DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate` property. This property accepts a single `DataTemplate`. Nested `DataTemplate` definitions, like in your code, are generally not supported by WPF.

```
<ad:DockingManager>
    <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassAProject.xaml" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>

    <ad:LayoutRoot>
        <ad:LayoutPanel>
            <ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <ad:LayoutDocumentPane />
            </ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </ad:LayoutPanel>
    </ad:LayoutRoot>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

---

### Solution 2: Implicit `DataTemplate`

In more advanced scenarios you display different views based on different models. If the displayed content depends on the data type of the model alone (like in your case), the recommended approach is to provide implicit `DataTemplate` definitions.

WPF will automatically apply an implicit `DataTemplate` to every data type that matches the `DataTemplate.TargetType` of this template.
The `DataTemplate` is implicit, if it has no explicit `x:Key` value assigned. To ensure that the `DataTemplate` can actually be applied automatically, the `DataTemplate` must also be defined in the same resource scope as the target type. E.g., defining the `DataTemplate` in `Application.Resources` of *App.xaml*, would make the template to be applied automatically in the application scope.

```
<ad:DockingManager>
    <ad:DockingManager.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassAViewModel}">
            <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassAProject.xaml" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassBViewModel}">
            <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassBProject.xaml" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassCViewModel}">
            <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassCProject.xaml" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ad:DockingManager.Resources>

    <ad:LayoutRoot>
        <ad:LayoutPanel>
            <ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <ad:LayoutDocumentPane>

                </ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
            </ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </ad:LayoutPanel>
    </ad:LayoutRoot>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

---

### Solution 3: `DataTemplateSelector`

The previous solution, which uses implicit `DataTemplate` definitions, can be replaced with a `DataTemplateSelector`. `DataTemplateSelector` is another WPF concept to apply a `DataTemplate` selectively.
A `DataTemplateSelector` is the recommended choice, if selecting a `DataTemplate` may depend on more complex constraints, than the model's data type alone. It allows to e.g. evaluate the data item and chose the appropriate template based on certain criteria.

To define a template selector, you have to extend `DataTemplateSelector`, which is expected to return a `DataTemplate`.
The easiest way is to define the templates in *App.xaml* resource dictionary using an `x:Key` and then select from them based on the condition.
`DockingManger` accepts a template selector by assigning the `DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector` property:

**App.xaml**
Define the explicit `DataTemplate` using `x:Key`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubclassAViewModelTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassAViewModel}">
        <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassAProject.xaml" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubclassBViewModelTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassBViewModel}">
        <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassBProject.xaml" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubclassCViewModelTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:SubclassCViewModel}">
        <Frame Source="Pages/SubclassCProject.xaml" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

**DocumentManagerTemplateSelector.cs**
The following code uses the Switch Expression, which is available since C# 8.0. It can be replaced with a switch statement or cascaded if-statements.

```
class DocumentManagerTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  #region Overrides of DataTemplateSelector

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    return item switch
    {
      SubclassAViewModel _ => Application.Current.Resources["SubclassAViewModelTemplate"] as DataTemplate,
      SubclassBViewModel _ => Application.Current.Resources["SubclassBViewModelTemplate"] as DataTemplate,
      SubclassCViewModel _ => Application.Current.Resources["SubclassCViewModelTemplate"] as DataTemplate,
      _ => base.SelectTemplate(item, container)
    };
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ad:DockingManager>
    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
      <local:DocumentManagerTemplateSelector />
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>

    <ad:LayoutRoot>
        <ad:LayoutPanel>
            <ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <ad:LayoutDocumentPane>

                </ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
            </ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </ad:LayoutPanel>
    </ad:LayoutRoot>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is it also possible to have multiple 'LayoutDocumentPane' - one for each DataType? And how do i address the correct objects to the 'LayoutPane'? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630628/avalondock-multiple-layoutdocumentpane-with-different-observablecollection-conta

Comment: I have posted an answer to your linked question.