# AvalonDock multiple LayoutDocumentPane with different ObservableCollection containing dynamic created UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, avalondock

I have a AvalonDock based UI with at least three static LayoutDocumentPanes. How can i dynamically fill those Panes with different UserControl Collections?
I figured out, that i can set a `DocumentSource` for the whole DockingManager and this Collection then can be used to generate elements for all panes.

Can I use multiple source collections or can i filter my collection for each LayoutDocumentPane?

```
<xcad:DockingManager  
            DocumentsSource="{Binding MyUserControls1}">
          
            <xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
                        <local:MyUserControl/>   
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcad:DockingManager.Resources>

    <xcad:LayoutRoot>
        <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockWidth="6*">
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                                <!-- UserControls from ObservableCollection 1-->
                                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup >
                            <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane >
                                <!-- UserControls from ObservableCollection 2-->
                                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup >
                            <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane >
                                <!-- UserControls from ObservableCollection 3-->
                                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup >
                </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
        </xcad:LayoutPanel>
     </xcad:LayoutRoot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the layout dynamically, you have to implement `ILayoutUpdateStrategy` and assign it to `DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy`. This strategy is invoked when ever you add an item to either `DockingManager.DocumentsSource` or `DockingManager.AnchorablesSource`. You can handle layout details before or after the adding of the content.

Note that an individual `DataTemplate` for each document model is still required (see [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63637353/3141792)). `ILayoutUpdateStrategy` only handles layout, but not content rendering.

You have to add all documents of different type to a common source collection.
I recommend to introduce an interface e.g., `IDocument` which is required to be implemented by each document type. This allows to store them in a common collection of type `IDocument` and enables polymorphism when iterating the collection.
You can then bind a `ObservableCollection<IDocument>` to the `DockingManager.DocumentsSource`.

The following example also creates the required layout (due to the grouping constraint). Because it will add mising layout elements to the `LayoutPanel` of `DockingManager.Layout`, the layout is handled *before* the content is added. Therefore in case of the grouped documents, there is no need to predefine the `LayoutRoot`:

**LayoutUpdateStrategy.cs**

```
public class LayoutUpdateStrategy : ILayoutUpdateStrategy
{
  #region Implementation of ILayoutUpdateStrategy

  public bool BeforeInsertAnchorable(
    LayoutRoot layout,
    LayoutAnchorable anchorableToShow,
    ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
  {
    return false;
  }

  public void AfterInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableShown)
  {
  }

  // Creates a new LayoutDocumentPane for each document model type.
  // All grouped documents will reside in a common LayoutDocumentPaneGroup.
  public bool BeforeInsertDocument(
    LayoutRoot layout,
    LayoutDocument documentToShow,
    ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
  {
    if (destinationContainer?.FindParent<LayoutFloatingWindow>() != null)
    {
      // Return 'false' as the strategy hasn't performed any action
      return false;
    }

    LayoutDocumentPane existingDocumentsPane = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().FirstOrDefault(
      pane => pane.Children.Any(
        layoutDocument => layoutDocument.Content.GetType() == documentToShow.Content.GetType()));

    if (existingDocumentsPane != null)
    {
      existingDocumentsPane.Children.Add(documentToShow);
    }
    else
    {
      // Get the existing LayoutDocumentPaneGroup
      LayoutDocumentPaneGroup paneGroup = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>().FirstOrDefault();

      // Create a new LayoutDocumentPaneGroup if there is none in the current layout
      if (paneGroup == null)
      {
        paneGroup = new LayoutDocumentPaneGroup();
        layout.RootPanel.Children.Add(paneGroup);
      }

      // Create a new LayoutDocumentPane for the new document type
      var pane = new LayoutDocumentPane(documentToShow);
      paneGroup.Children.Add(pane);
    }

    // Return 'true' as the strategy has performed any action
    return true;
  }

  public void AfterInsertDocument(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutDocument documentToShow)
  {
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding MyDocuments}">
    <DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
        <LayoutUpdateStrategy />
      </DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
  </DockingManager>
</Window>
```

Comment: thank you again for your answer - it's a good base to start from. In my xaml i would like to adress my existing LayoutDocumentPanes directly. Is it possible to select the element in the LayoutUpdateStrategy class by using the x:Name Attribute? Something like: `layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "ToolsPane");`

Comment: No. The `x:Name` directive will create a protected field to reference the named element in the owner of the elements namescope (which is e.g. the `MainWIndow`). Due to the access modifier this field is not accessible. Also you are not able to access the namescope without a reference to the owner. You can introduce a custom attached property in order to identify the layout elements by name. It might help to know that the order of the panes in their parent pane group collection is equal to the order of definition in the markup. First pane in markup is the first pane in descendants collection.

Comment: You can access them by index e.g. `layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().ElementAt(0).Children.Add(documentToShow);`

Comment: `x:Name` is a pure XAML directive. Obviously the AvalonDock has its limitations. It could have been implemented better. As I said before, you can create a custom attached property and apply it to the pane in XAML. This is very quickly done. You can then filter the panes by this value.